# get rsync to dereference symlinked dirs presented on cmdline like find -H

Tags: rsync, symlink

I'd love rsync to copy symlinks to dirs specified on the cmdline as dirs but leave all symlinks in the copied tree as is - like `find -H`, but the only way is a nasty hack of

```
rsync -aR --rsync-path='cd /sender/parent/dir/of/tree; rsync' symlinkeddir/ target
```

the issue there is that this becomes an exception in my rsync backup scripts just for this one set of paths so I can't use the same command (or more so, just ONE `rsync`) to do what I want. `find -H` -like behaviour would do it very nicely. :/

Answer (score 0):

If `somelink` is a symbolic link to a directory `somedir`, then

```
rsync -a somelink/. target/
```

copies the content of `somedir` into `target`.

If you only have relative symlinks that stay inside the source, then you can use

```
rsync -a --copy-unsafe-links somelink target/
```

If you want to preserve the symlink path inside the target, I don't think what you want to do can be done with rsync alone. You can do it with rsync plus a bit of shell code: loop over the sources, and specify the target subdirectory explicitly.

```
mkdir -p target/somelink
rsync -a somelink/. target/somelink
```

Comment: yes, quite - problem is i want the literal portion of 'somelink' copied too - mostly because ive got somelink1 2 and 3, so i need dirs somelink1 2 and 3 created in the target, thus the -R in my eg.

(beware! rsync -a somelink*/ target will merge somelink*'s contents into one dir with whatever's copied first taking precedence!)

Comment: @math Unless you can use the absolute/relative symlink trick (second proposal in my answer), I don't think you can do it with rsync alone. There are many possible workarounds, but not seamless ones. A loop over the sources where you specify the target subdirectory each time seems easiest to me.